# Avoiding lift with monad transformers

Tags: haskell, monads, monad-transformers

I have a problem to which a stack of monad transformers (or even one monad transformer) over `IO`. Everything is good, except that using lift before every action is terribly annoying! I suspect there is really nothing to do about that, but I thought I'd ask anyway.

I am aware of lifting entire blocks, but what if the code is really of mixed types? Would it not be nice if GHC threw in some syntactic sugar (for example, `<-$` = `<- lift`)?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

For all the standard [mtl](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/mtl) monads, you don't need `lift` at all. `get`, `put`, `ask`, `tell` — they all work in any monad with the right transformer somewhere in the stack. The missing piece is `IO`, and even there `liftIO` lifts an arbitrary IO action down an arbitrary number of layers.

This is done with typeclasses for each "effect" on offer: for example, [`MonadState`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/mtl/latest/doc/html/Control-Monad-State-Class.html) provides `get` and `put`. If you want to create your own `newtype` wrapper around a transformer stack, you can do `deriving (..., MonadState MyState, ...)` with the `GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving` extension, or roll your own instance:

```
instance MonadState MyState MyMonad where
  get = MyMonad get
  put s = MyMonad (put s)
```

You can use this to selectively expose or hide components of your combined transformer, by defining some instances and not others.

(You can easily extend this approach to all-new monadic effects you define yourself, by defining your own typeclass and providing boilerplate instances for the standard transformers, but all-new monads are rare; most of the time, you'll get by simply composing the standard set offered by mtl.)

Comment: Oh I think I feel stupid, you mentioned that in one of your previous answers, I could not understand it at the time. Now, I do thanks!

Answer (score 52):

You can make your functions monad-agnostic by using typeclasses instead of concrete monad stacks.

Let's say that you have this function, for example:

```
bangMe :: State String ()
bangMe = do
  str <- get
  put $ str ++ "!"
  -- or just modify (++"!")
```

Of course, you realize that it works as a transformer as well, so one could write:

```
bangMe :: Monad m => StateT String m ()
```

However, if you have a function that uses a different stack, let's say `ReaderT [String] (StateT String IO) ()` or whatever, you'll have to use the dreaded `lift` function! So how is that avoided?

The trick is to make the function signature even more generic, so that it says that the `State` monad can appear anywhere in the monad stack. This is done like this:

```
bangMe :: MonadState String m => m ()
```

This forces `m` to be a monad that supports state (virtually) anywhere in the monad stack, and the function will thus work without lifting for any such stack.

There's one problem, though; since `IO` isn't part of the `mtl`, it doesn't have a transformer (e.g. `IOT`) nor a handy type class per default. So what should you do when you want to lift IO actions arbitrarily?

To the rescue comes [`MonadIO`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/transformers/latest/doc/html/Control-Monad-IO-Class.html)! It behaves almost identically to `MonadState`, `MonadReader` etc, the only difference being that it has a slightly different lifting mechanism. It works like this: you can take any `IO` action, and use `liftIO` to turn it into a monad agnostic version. So:

```
action :: IO ()
liftIO action :: MonadIO m => m ()
```

By transforming all of the monadic actions you wish to use in this way, you can intertwine monads as much as you want without any tedious lifting.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! Beaten in timing by ehird though ;)

Comment: Me and ehird provide somewhat different solutions to this problem. It might be worth reading both of the responses to understand the alternatives you have :)

Comment: It's unfortunate so much boilerplate is needed.

Comment: For what it’s worth, this solution seems to require the `{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}` pragma.