# Monad Stack Penetration Classes with Free/Operational Monad Transformers?

Tags: haskell, monad-transformers, free-monad

Can there be mtl-like mechanism for monad transformers created by FreeT / ProgramT ?

My understanding of the history is as follows. Once upon a time monad transformer was invented. Then people started to stack monad transformers one on other, then found it annoying to insert `lift` everywhere. Then a couple of people invented monad classes, so that we can e.g. `ask :: m r` in any monad `m` such that `MonadReader r m` . This was possible by making every monad class *penetrate* every monad transformer, like

> `(Monoid w, MonadState s m) => MonadState s (WriterT w m)
>
>   MonadWriter w m => MonadWriter w (StateT s m)`

you need such pair of instance declarations for every pair of monad transformers, so when there's *n* monad transformers there's *n*^2 costs. This was not a large problem, however, because people will mostly use predefined monads and rarely create their own. The story so far I understand, and also is detailed e.g. in the following Q&A:

[Avoiding lift with Monad Transformers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9054731/avoiding-lift-with-monad-transformers)

Then my problem is with the new Free monads http://hackage.haskell.org/package/free and Operational monads http://hackage.haskell.org/package/operational . They allow us to write our own DSL and use it as monads, just by defining the language as some algebraic `data` type (Operational doesn't even need `Functor` instances). Good news is that we can have monads and monad transformers for free; then how about monad classes? Bad news is that the assumption "we rarely define our own monad transformers" no longer holds.

As an attempt to understand this problem, I made two `ProgramT`s and made them penetrate each other;

https://github.com/nushio3/practice/blob/master/operational/exe-src/test-05.hs

The `operational` package does not support monad classes so I took another implementation `minioperational` and modified it to work as I need; https://github.com/nushio3/minioperational

Still, I needed the specialized instance declaration

> `instance (Monad m, Operational ILang m) => Operational ILang (ProgramT SLang m) where`

because the general declaration of the following form leads to undecidable instances.

> `instance (Monad m, Operational f m) => Operational f (ProgramT g m) where`

My question is that how can we make it easier to let our Operational monads penetrate each other. Or, is my wish to have penetration for any Operational monad ill-posed.

I'd also like to know the correct technical term for *penetration* :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I tried a bit different approach, which gives at least a partial answer. Since stacking monads can be sometimes problematic, and we know all our monads are constructed from some data type, I tried instead to combine the data types.

I feel more comfortable with `MonadFree` so I used it, but I suppose a similar approach could be used for `Operational` as well.

Let's start with the definition of our data types:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveFunctor, FlexibleContexts,
             FlexibleInstances, FunctionalDependencies #-}
import Control.Monad
import Control.Monad.Free

data SLang x = ReadStr (String -> x) | WriteStr String x
  deriving Functor
data ILang x = ReadInt (Int -> x) | WriteInt Int x
  deriving Functor
```

In order to combine two functors together for using them in a free monad, let's define their coproduct:

```
data EitherF f g a = LeftF (f a) | RightF (g a)
  deriving Functor
```

If we create a free monad over `EitherF f g`, we can call the commands from both of them. In order to make this process transparent, we can use [MPTC](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Multi-parameter_type_class) to allow conversion from each of the functor into the target one:

```
class Lift f g where
    lift :: f a -> g a
instance Lift f f where
    lift = id

instance Lift f (EitherF f g) where
    lift = LeftF
instance Lift g (EitherF f g) where
    lift = RightF
```

now we can just call `lift` and convert either part into the coproduct.

With a helper function

```
wrapLift :: (Functor g, Lift g f, MonadFree f m) => g a -> m a
wrapLift = wrap . lift . fmap return
```

we can finally create generic functions that allow us to call commands from anything we can lift into a functor:

```
readStr :: (Lift SLang f, MonadFree f m) => m String
readStr = wrapLift $ ReadStr id

writeStr :: (Lift SLang f, MonadFree f m) => String -> m ()
writeStr x = wrapLift $ WriteStr x ()

readInt :: (Lift ILang f, MonadFree f m) => m Int
readInt = wrapLift $ ReadInt id

writeInt :: (Lift ILang f, MonadFree f m) => Int -> m ()
writeInt x = wrapLift $ WriteInt x ()
```

Then, the program can be expressed as

```
myProgram :: (Lift ILang f, Lift SLang f, MonadFree f m) => m ()
myProgram = do
  str <- readStr
  writeStr "Length of that str is"
  writeInt $ length str
  n <- readInt
  writeStr "you wanna have it n times; here we go:"
  writeStr $ replicate n 'H'
```

without defining any further instances.

---

While all the above works nicely, the problem is how to generically run such composed free monads. I don't know if it is even possible, to have a fully generic, composable solution.

If we have just one base functor, we can run it as

```
runSLang :: Free SLang x -> String -> (String, x)
runSLang = f
  where
    f (Pure x)              s  = (s, x)
    f (Free (ReadStr g))    s  = f (g s) s
    f (Free (WriteStr s' x)) _ = f x s'
```

If we have two, we need to thread the state of both of them:

```
runBoth :: Free (EitherF SLang ILang) a -> String -> Int -> ((String, Int), a)
runBoth = f
  where
    f (Pure x)                       s i  = ((s, i), x)
    f (Free (LeftF  (ReadStr g)))     s i = f (g s) s i
    f (Free (LeftF  (WriteStr s' x))) _ i = f x s' i
    f (Free (RightF (ReadInt g)))     s i = f (g i) s i
    f (Free (RightF (WriteInt i' x))) s _ = f x s i'
```

I guess one possibility would be to express running the functors using `iter :: Functor f => (f a -> a) -> Free f a -> a` from [free](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/free/3.4.2/doc/html/Control-Monad-Free.html#v:iter) and then create a similar, combining function

```
iter2 :: (Functor f, Functor g)
      => (f a -> a) -> (g a -> a) -> Free (EitherF f g) a -> a
```

But I haven't had time to try it out.

Comment: Thank you, Petr. With your help I understood how to combine two type constructors using Either over `(* -> *)` .
https://github.com/nushio3/practice/blob/master/operational/exe-src/test-06.hs
Writing composable interpreters are just as easy:
https://github.com/nushio3/practice/blob/master/operational/exe-src/test-07.hs
We can even compose more than two languages at the cost of `OverlappingInstances` .
https://github.com/nushio3/practice/blob/master/operational/exe-src/test-08.hs