# Haskell: Why is this monad transformation wrong?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, monads, monad-transformers

I am studying monad transformers, and I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9054731/avoiding-lift-with-monad-transformers) SO post about how to avoid `lift`s.

My thought was that `MonadIO` are monads in which `IO` can be embedded, and `MonadWriter w` are monads in which `WriterT w` can be embedded. So I wrote the code below (read, accumulate and record numbers until we get a zero), where a working version using explicit `lift` is in comments. But GHC complains. What am I doing wrong?

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}
import Control.Monad.IO.Class
import Control.Monad.Writer.Class (MonadWriter)
import Control.Monad.Trans.Reader
import Control.Monad.Trans.Writer

-- f :: ReaderT Int (WriterT [String] IO) Int
-- m1 = ReaderT, m2 = WriterT
f :: (MonadWriter [String] m1, MonadIO m2) => m1 (m2 (IO Int))
f = do
    s <- liftIO getLine
    tell ["Input: " ++ s] -- lift $ tell ["Input: " ++ s]
    let i = read s :: Int
    if i == 0
       then ask
       else local (+i) f

main = do
    rst <- runWriterT $ runReaderT f 0
    print rst
```

Comment: How does GHC complain? (Always add the error message)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> My thought was that MonadIO are monads in which IO can be embedded, and MonadWriter w are monads in which WriterT w can be embedded.

That's not completely correct. `MonadIO`s can use `liftIO`, and [`MonadWriter`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/mtl-2.2.1/docs/Control-Monad-Writer-Lazy.html) can use `tell`. Therefore, if you want to use `liftIO`, `tell`, `ask` and `local` in the same context/monad without lifting, the **single** monad you use must be an instance of all of them:

```
f :: ( MonadWriter [String] m -- monad supports  tell   :: [String] -> m ()
     , MonadReader Int      m -- monad supports  ask    ::             m Int
     , MonadIO              m -- monad supports  liftIO :: IO a     -> m a
     )         =>  m Int      -- only a single m
```

Note that you cannot use `transformer`, but `mtl` to get automatic lifting. Therefore, the imports also change:

```
import Control.Monad.Reader (runReaderT, MonadReader)
import Control.Monad.Writer (runWriterT, MonadWriter)
import Control.Monad.IO.Class (liftIO, MonadIO)
```

The import of `MonadIO` does not change since `IO` actions never get lifted automatically.

By the way, your use of `runWriterT` and `runReaderT` already removes all ambiguities the transformer stack, since this will use

```
ReaderT Int (WriterT [String] IO Int)
```

Comment: There's `lifted-base` (IIRC) for lifted `IO` actions.